# Scrolling on a GTK3 Scale widget does not work correctly

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3

When I run this code

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class GUI(Gtk.Window):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(title="Scale Bug")

    # Threshold Slider Mask
    ad1 = Gtk.Adjustment(0, 0, 255, 1, 20, 0)
    self.scale = Gtk.Scale(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, adjustment=ad1)
    self.scale.connect("button-release-event", self.on_scale_changed)
    self.scale.connect("key_release_event", self.on_scale_changed)
    self.scale.connect("scroll-event", self.on_scale_changed)
    self.scale.set_size_request(50, 350)

    # Main Container
    self.main_container = Gtk.Fixed()
    self.main_container.put(self.scale, 10, 10)

    # Main Window
    self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
    self.add(self.main_container)

    self.resize(50, 400)
    self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)

  def on_scale_changed(self, scale, data):
    print(scale.get_value())

win = GUI()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

win.set_default_size(1000, 800)

win.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

on **Ubuntu 12.04** I got a strange behaviour when I change the scale value.

It works fine if I use the mouse buttons and keyboard keys but if I use the scrolling wheel of my mouse it shows the correct value at the scale bar but the following print command reading the value from the scale object gives me the value before the change.

This happens only for the **scroll-event**.

Is this a bug or did I forget something?